# Exporting templated inline functions - definition of function dllimport not allowed

Tags: c++, templates, dll, dllexport

I'm trying to implement math library but I'm stuck on exporting. I have a template class for 2-dimensional vector:

vector2.h:

```
    template <typename T>
class GE_API Vector2
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;

    // Indexation
    T& operator [] (const size_t i);
    const T& operator [] (const size_t i) const;

    bool operator == (const Vector2& v) const;
    bool operator != (const Vector2& v) const;

    // Negation
    const Vector2 operator - () const;

    // Assignement 
    const Vector2& operator = (const Vector2& v);

    const Vector2& operator += (const Vector2& v);

    const Vector2& operator -= (const Vector2& v);

    template <typename S>
    const Vector2& operator *= (const S& s);

    template <typename S>
    const Vector2& operator /= (const S& s);

    const Vector2 operator + (const Vector2& v) const;
    const Vector2 operator + (const T& s) const;
    const Vector2 operator - (const Vector2& v) const;
    const Vector2 operator - (const T& s) const;

    template <typename S>
    const Vector2 operator * (const S& s) const;

    const Vector2 operator * (const Vector2& v) const;

    template <typename S>
    const Vector2 operator / (const S& s) const;

    const Vector2 operator / (const Vector2& v) const;
};



template <typename T>
GE_API const T dot(const Vector2<T>& a, const Vector2<T>& b);



template <typename T>
GE_API const T length(const Vector2<T>& v);

//..and other functionality
#include <vector2.inl>
```

Definitions of operators and functions are in separate file vector2.inl which is included in header file. GE_API is standard dllimport/export macro. Problem is that when I try to export this class and functions defined in vector2.h header file I'm getting errors on definitions of operators that definition of dllimport function is not allowed. Why is that and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you don't need to specify dllimport/export for your class.
Because all source code will be avaliable to the user and only anoe thing that he heeds is to include vactor2.h header into his project.